# Abstract inheritance from models in third party Django packages

Tags: python, django, django-models

To do abstract model inheritance in Django, we put

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

in the parent model. Does this mean that it is impossible to abstractly inherit from a model that does not have this *Meta* statement? Specifically, is it not possible to abstractly inherit from a model in an existing model in a third party package (unless we change that model)?

Here is an example to clarify what I am asking. Let's say there is Django package called *djangofoo* that I've installed in my project's *INSTALLED_APPS*.  In *djangofoo.models*, let's say we have

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I could sub-class from *Person* in one my own apps as follows

```
from djangofoo.models import Person

class MyPerson(Person):
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

However, this is a concrete inheritance. Is it possible to do an abstract inheritance? Here's a fictitious example of the kind of magic that I am looking for:

```
from djangofoo.models import Person

AbstractPerson = abstractify(Person)

class MyPerson(AbstractPerson):
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Of course I could change the *Person* model definition in *djangofoo.models* to add the appropriate *abstract = True* statement, but it would be preferable not to have to do that for obvious reasons.

Comment: Technically, you cannot abstractly inherit from concrete models. And there is no such `abstractify` tool available right now (I mean, anything equivalent to it). However, this sounds really interesting to implement.

Comment: Sir, you've given me a fine homework for tonight :)